# Square brackets meaning string wont work

Tags: jquery, square-bracket

I am a bit stuck,  trying to use this jquery line to enter a result from a select option into a text area

This doesnt work

```
  $("#id[txt_17]").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("name"));
```

This does

```
$("#idtxt_17").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("name"));
```

The [ ] are coded in via an oscommerce plugin and I have no idea of the importance of them, or what me removing them would do, but I am wondering if there is a workaround so I can leave them in.   I tried creating a variable referencing the id but it still didnt work because of the square brackets.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [jQuery - Category: Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers.

replace:

```
$("#id[txt_17]").val
```

with:

```
$("#id\\[txt_17\\]").val
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tGLVy/)

Answer (score 1):

Escape the brackets:

```
$("#id\\[txt_17\\]")
```