# Jquery not working with square brackets in rails 4 app

Tags: jquery

I've looked at these posts: 
[jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)
[Escape square brackets when assigning a class name to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466103/escape-square-brackets-in-a-class-name)
[Square brackets meaning string wont work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319195/square-brackets-meaning-string-wont-work)

But I still can't get jquery to properly handle a name with square brackets.

When I used jquery with a rails form_tag I had no problems because the name of the radio button was simply "option", without square brackets. When I switched to a rails form_for, rails included the object "resource" and thus the name of the radio button became "resource[option]".  These square brackets caused jquery to stop working.  As you'll note below, I tried using // to handle the brackets, but it still doesn't work.

This code with a form_tag worked:

```
$("input:radio[name='option']").click(function(){  
  if(this.value == 'no_<%= user.id %>' && this.checked){
    $("#fields_<%= user.id %>").hide();
  }
  if(this.value == 'yes_<%= user.id %>' && this.checked){
    $("#fields_<%= user.id %>").show();
  }
});
```

The code below with form_for(@resource) does not work:

```
$("input:radio[name='resource\\[option\\]']").click(function(){
  if(this.value == 'resource_option_no_<%= user.id %>' && this.checked){
    $("#fields_<%= user.id %>").hide();
  }
  if(this.value == 'resource_option_yes_<%= user.id %>' && this.checked){
    $("#fields_<%= user.id %>").show();
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you shouldn't need to escape the square brackets, what does your browser console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you **delimit** the search value **or** you **escape** meta-characters **but not both**. Thus use either:

```
$("input:radio[name='resource[option]']")....
```

Or:

```
$("input:radio[name=resource\\[option\\]]")....
```

```js
console.log( 'Escaped', $("input:radio[name=resource\\[option\\]]").val() );

console.log( 'Delimited', $("input:radio[name='resource[option]']").val() );

$(':radio[name=resource\\[option\\]]').on('change', function() {
    console.log( 'Change event fired checkbox checked?', this.checked );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="resource[option]" value="3432"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.   It works nicely now.

Comment: No problem. Remember that whereas you can select only one answer as the best answer, you may up-vote more than one answer as useful. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Attribute value selector there is no need to escape `[]`. Also I would recommend you to use `change` event and `.toggle(boolean)` function.

```
$("input:radio[name='resource[option]']").change(function(){
    $("#fields_<%= user.id %>").toggle(this.value == 'resource_option_yes_<%= user.id %>' && this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.